# Filter GitHub Pull Requests by Reviews

Tags: github

Is there currently any way to filter GitHub Pull Requests based on the status of the new Reviews feature? (i.e. changes requested, approved)

Previously, I'd do something like `LGTM in:comments` or filter based on reactions, depending on the team.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub.com has recently releasedthe preview API for Review Requests:

- [Blog
  post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2016-12-16-review-requests-api/)
- [API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/)

You can [list all pull requests for a given repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) and then for each pull request ID you can query the reviews on that pull request by using the [List reviews on a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request) endpoint.

*Note: You can do this as I've explained above. Maybe one day the [list all pull requests endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) will have a parameter to filter by review status, but I don't see one just yet in the API docs.*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the API mentioned in [bitoiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174076/bitoiu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250537/6309), the search filter now (January 2017, 4 months later) supports the review status for pull requests!

See "[Filter pull request reviews and review requests](https://github.com/blog/2306-filter-pull-request-reviews-and-review-requests)"

> To make it easier to find the pull requests that need your attention, you can now [filter by review status](https://help.github.com/articles/filtering-pull-requests-by-review-status) from your repository pull request index.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/22212644/7711bef8-e15f-11e6-8331-5973635cd6ee.png]

> You can also filter pull requests that have been reviewed by a specific user and quickly locate those that have required your review in the past to decide which needs your attention first.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/22213591/bdedfab4-e162-11e6-8777-07bbcbd37066.png]